# Compare two strings in Javascript using regex as wildcard

Tags: javascript, regex, testing

There are various examples on this, but also various scenarios, and I haven't been able to find my specific scenario, that's why I'm adding my question here

I have two string to compare. One of them contains a variable that in the second was replaced by a word or phrase, for example:

- variable = "group of documents"
- String 1: "The following %%variable%% has been signed"
- String 2: "The following group of documents has been signed"

I'd like to use javascript to compare both strings, using regex or any other solution to just allow the comparison procedure to tell me if the strings are identical without taking into account the variable that was replaced by either a single word or a phrase like in the example.

Thanks

Comment: @markalex, did you read the placemarker in the comment box before you started typing?

Comment: Is that an excuse to ignore the word "avoid"?

Comment: @trincot, placeholders don't have power over me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your string1 into regex, that can be used to match other strings. To do this:

1. escape regex symbols,
2. replace everything matching `%%.+?%%` with `.+`,
3. add `^` and `$` to prevent partial matching.

```js
const string1 = "The following %%variable%% has %%been%% signed"
const string2 = "The following jdfkdfk dfv dfv has been signed"
const r = new RegExp('^' + 
                string1
                    .replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')
                    .replace(/%%.+?%%/g, '.+') +
                '$')

console.log("Resulting pattern: " + r)
console.log(r.test(string2))
console.log(r.test('asd'))
```

Comment: oh boy @markalex ... that's exactly what I was needing... can we be friends? :D Thanks a lot!